# How to create legends with triangular end boxes in arcGIS?

Tags: legend, arcgis

I simply want my legend which is now in the form of the left bar in the following image, to be shown in the form of the bar in the right side. I couldn't find anything related for arcGIS. those anyone know?

Thank you so much for your help.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is an elegant way to do this, only a work-around:

In Layout View, convert the legend to graphics. (Make sure your data and legend are in their final product state as your legend will no longer be dynamically linked to your data).

Right-click on the legend and ungroup the elements in the legend. Repeat as many times as necessary in order to be able to select an individual rectangle.

Manually convert the two rectangles into triangles. One way to do this would be to activate the "Draw" toolbar and draw white polygons over parts of each rectangle.

Once finished, regroup everything.

Again, not the prettiest solution but I don't believe ArcMap has this functionality.

Good luck!

Tom